# 'XRegExp' is undefined using ie11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, xregexp

I'm using XRegExp for checking unicode regular expressions. It works without problem in any browser I have tested except in IE11.

In my script I define the regex to check as:

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^[\\p{L}']...+$");
```

And in ie11 I get the following errors:

> SCRIPT5009: 'Symbol' is undefined
>   xregexp.all.js (1730,11)
>   SCRIPT5009: 'XregExp' is undefined
>   jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js (2,31232)

How can I solve this in ie11? I have checked and ie11 is not running in compatibility mode. As well I have read the documentation on xregexp.com but I can't see any way to solve this issue.

I will appreciate some guide to find the solution and if it's possible an explanation why ie11 behaves like that.

Comment: What version of XRegExp do you have? It was broken in IE around July of this year, but has apparently been fixed since: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/issues/254

Comment: @JLRishe I'm using the script from https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js which uses 4.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error regarding `Symbol` is because the latest version of XRegExp uses `Symbol` which is not defined in IE11. An [issue](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/issues/254) was raised about the problem. Your choices are:

1. Revert to an older version of XRegExp that does not use `Symbol`.
2. Install a polyfill for `Symbol` before loading XRegExp so that `Symbol` is present.
3. Wait for a newer release of XRegExp that is compiled with a polyfill. The fix [has been merged](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/pull/255) but I don't see a release with this fix yet.

The error regarding `XregExp` just looks like a typo to me. The name is `XRegExp`, not `XregExp`.